# Why do people define object extends its companion class?

Tags: scala

I find this kind of code is very common in Lift framework, written like this: 
 `object BindHelpers extends BindHelpers {}`
What does this mean?

Answer (score 6):

In this case, `BindHelpers` is a trait and not a class. Let `foo()` to be a method defined in `BindHelpers`, to access it you can either.

1. Use it through the companion object: `BindHelpers.foo()`
2. Mix the trait `BindHelpers` in a class and thus be able to access the methods inside of it.

For instance:

```
class MyClass extends MyParentClass with BindHelpers {
  val a = foo()
}
```

The same techniques is used in Scalatest for `ShouldMatchers` for instance.

Comment: Have you noticed that in Lift Mappers you write the same pattern, and that extends it's companion class but not trait.

Answer (score 3):

You can find [David Pollak's answer](http://groups.google.com/group/liftweb/browse_thread/thread/532cff6c0740d007) to the same question in the liftweb group.

Answer (score 2):

It's interesting for an `object` to extend its companion class because it will have the same type as the class.

If `object BindHelpers` didn't extend BindHelpers, it would be of type `BindHelpers$`.

Comment: So what value does this add?

Comment: E.g. to provide a default implementation.

Comment: The companion does not seem to be the right place for a default implementation. That's what the usual class hierarchy is for.

Answer (score 2):

It might be that the pattern here is other. I don't know Lift to answer this, but there's a problem with `object` in that they are not mockable. So, if you define everything in a `class`, which can be mocked, and then just makes the object extend it, you can mock the class and use it instead of the object inside your tests.